# Angular: Format date using pipe with custom string

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime

I am new to angular. I used pipe to format date. I used following but, didn't work.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items; index as i" [attr.data-rel]="'sometext-' + item.startTime | dateFormat ">
```

If i remove either `'timeslot-' +` or `| dateFormat` it works but, with string concatenation it doesn't work.

Following works.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items; index as i" [attr.data-rel]="'sometext-' + item.startTime">
```

Or

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items; index as i" [attr.data-rel]="item.startTime | dateFormat ">
```

Comment: what is the expected result? someText - (dateformated) or (sometext-date)formated?

Comment: @cucuru expected result: `someText-dateformatted`

Comment: `<tr *ngFor="let item of items; index as i" [attr.data-rel]="'sometext-' + (item.startTime | dateFormat )">`

Comment: wrap `(item.startTime | dateFormat )` between parenthesis

Comment: @NadhirFalta Cool. It works please post it as answer. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wrap `(item.startTime | dateFormat )` between parenthesis

`<tr *ngFor="let item of items; index as i" [attr.data-rel]="'sometext-' + (item.startTime | dateFormat )">`

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'dateFormat' })
export class DateFormat implements PipeTransform {
  transform(date: Date, text: string): string {
    return text + date.toString();
  }
}
```

call it like this

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items; index as i" [attr.data-rel]="item.startTime | dateFormat : 'sometext'  ">
```